# How to integrate Payseal in ASPNET

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway

Anyone, plz, provide me the details of integrating payseal(ICICI) in my website.. They hav given some testing code.. But, I couldn't understand it.. If I get any code sample, it will be useful for me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok..I found the solution.. Just add the dll which is provided by them. They hav given the sample test pages. In that, run the aspx file, "testssl.aspx" by changing the function setmerchantdetails with your information like merchant id,response page etc., like

```
objMerchant.setMerchantDetails("00001212", "00001212", "00001212", "", transactionid, "Orderno", "http://localhost/SFAClient/SFAResponse.aspx", "POST", "INR", "INVoiceno", "req.Preauthorization", "1550.00", "GMT+05:30", "Ext1", "Ext2", "Ext3", "Ext4", "Ext5");
```

That will take u to the icici payseal page. From that the customer hav to response. After finishing the payment, it will directly return to the response page designed by you(http://localhost/SFAClient/SFAResponse.aspx).

Hope, it will help others!!!!

Comment: Any reference links there to integrate ICICI Api in dot net.